# Error in fetching latitude and longitude using google-maps

Tags: javascript, express, google-maps-api-3, nodes, geocoding

I want to get latitude and longitude of few locations which are stored in my json.
I am getting the latitude and longitude but the problem is order in which they are recieved is absurd.

Example

`x= [ { "city" : "Mumbai" , "location" : "India"},{ "city" : "Mumbai" , "location" : "India"},{ "city" : "New Delhi" , "location" : "India"},{ "city" : "Mumbai" , "location" : "India"} ]`

Expected `lt : [ "19.075" ,"19.075" ,"28.613" ,"19.075" ]`

But I am getting output in different order.
Output :

`lt : [ "19.075" ,"19.075"  ,"19.075" ,"28.613"]`

`lt : [ "19.075" , "28.613" ,"19.075" ,"19.075" ]`

`lt : [ "19.075" , "28.613","19.075" ,"19.075" ]`

`lt : [ "28.613" ,"19.075" ,"19.075" ,"19.075" ]`

Code

---

```
lt=[];
lng=[];
for(k=0;k<x.length;k++)
{
  console.log(x[k].city);
  request({ url : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?  address='+x[k].city+'&region='+x[k].country+'&key=AIzaSyCdZL4cxbxZrLf2El5FeNT2Kh_uqw3b61Y' , json: true },function (error, response, body) { 
      lt.push(body.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
      console.log(lt);
      lg.push(body.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
    });
}
```

Comment: My first suspicion is that your asynchronous requests aren't completing in the same order you're creating them.

Comment: Yes exactly ! How to avoid that ??

Comment: lookup how to do a setTimeout in a loop, it's like the #1 question, and the same applies to any async function, not just setTimeout...

Comment: @dandavis could you help me a bit more ??

Comment: wrap a self-invoking function around the loop body code, passing `k` to the function as a formal parameter named `k`. then inside, set the `lt` array index manually instead of using push(). eg. `lt[k]=body.results...` that way, they can't get out of order, and the index will be correct because of the function wrap.

Comment: var z=0;
    for(k=0;k<x.length;k++)
    {
      request({ url : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+x[k].city+'&region='+x[k].country+'&key=AIzaSyCdZL4cxbxZrLf2El5FeNT2Kh_uqw3b61Y' , json: true },function (error, response, body) { 
          lt[z]=body.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
          console.log(lt);
          lg[z++]=body.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        });
    
    }

Comment: I made the above changes. But yet the order is not correct.

Comment: Why does the order matter?  What are you using the results for?

Comment: order matters because i am storing city along with data in data basee. I am having a list of city in first array and location in second . So , order must be specific.